# How do you construct a do while loop in Apache-Camel?

Tags: xml, apache-camel

I'm new to Apache-Camel, I want to find out how to execute a `<to url=direct:Channel>` at least once before looping it based on a condition/expression.

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't a good do while loop - it has been [asked for](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.apache.camel.user/10550) but not done yet as far as I can see.

Can you just resend it to `direct:Channel` (a circular loop, based on a condition) ?

Perhaps combine with `.loop(50)` to give some extra efficiency if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using DynamicRouter.

It uses an Expression class to determine the next route to dispatch the exchange. If the expression returns null it means that it will stop routing.

This way you can evaluate the exchange contents and continue routing to the same route until you decide is time to stop, and then return null.

For an example, please refer to my answer on [this other similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240882/is-there-a-while-loop-in-camel/33895061)